# how to style chart_pie font_size gem "chartkick"

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, chartkick

I tried different ways nothing work for me
I want to change the font size for it

```
   <%= pie_chart @user.products.group(:name).count, library: {fontSize: 10}  %>
```

Comment: I have experience to change the font size using the options provided by the Chartkick library, but it did not work either. Chartkick uses chart.js under the hood, so if you want to style the chart, I think it would be easier to use chart.js directly.